# Upgrading Angular getting 404 Not Found for scripts in Index

Tags: angular

I've just upgrade my project to Angular 4.0.0 and Angular CLI 1.0.0 from Angular 2.4.7 and Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.31. Since upgrading I am getting the following errors:

```
font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
material-icons.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
global-styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
hammer.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

These relate to script references in my index.html below. I haven't change the structure since upgrading, does anyone know why I am getting these errors?

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tellurium Platform</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/library/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./global-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/library/css/material-icons.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  <!--For Material 2 slider elements-->
  <script src="./app/library/js/hammer.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="canvas">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your dependencie into `.angular-cli.json` file under scripts like this

```
 "scripts": [
        ....,
        "./app/library/js/hammer.js"
      ],
```

> from the latest angulae cli you have to add all external files(css and js) under the script and style tag in the angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this official **[release notes](https://github.com/angular/quickstart#updating-to-a-newer-version-of-the-quickstart-repo)** the folder structure is changed and you should be changing the path as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/app/library/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./global-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/app/library/css/material-icons.css">
```

Comment: Thanks but as you can see there is an error with global-styles-css which is in the same directory as index.html. Pardeep answer is correct the dependencies must now be angular-cli.json